# applying darkreader globally to a nextjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

`ReferenceError: window is not defined` during a reload but works otherwise.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    enableDarkMode({
      brightness: 100,
      contrast: 100,
      sepia: 10,
    });
  });
```

Tried useEffect and conditionally checking, still gives the error. The code works just fine when applied to specific pages of the app but doesn't work for more "global" components like wrappers and such.

https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader